# Undesired output in simple 2D array program

Tags: c, arrays, output

As a homework problem, I have to create a simple program that outputs 5 **distinct** cards from a standard 52 card deck.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

void deal(char input_array[5][4]);

char deck[52][4]={"AcS","02S","03S","04S","05S","06S","07S","08S","09S","10S","JaS","QuS","KiS",
"AcH","02H","03H","04H","05H","06H","07H","08H","09H","10H","JaH","QuH","KiH","AcD","02D",
"03D","04D","05D","06D","07D","08D","09D","10D","JaD","QuD","KiD","AcC","02C","03C","04C",
"05C","06C","07C","08C","09C","10C","JaC","QuC","KiC"};

main()
{
    int index;
    char hand[5][4];
    deal(hand);

    for(index = 0; index < 5; index++){
        printf("%s\n", hand[index]);
    }
}

void deal(char input_array[5][4])
{
    int i, j, randInt, count = 0;
    //srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* outer for loop used to assign 5 cards to array */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        /* random int generated between 0 and 51, so a random card can be picked from the deck array */
        randInt = (rand() % 52);

        /* inner for loop checks each time whether the card already exists in the input_array. if it exists, count is incremented by 1 */
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){

            if(strcmp(input_array[j], deck[randInt]) == 0){
                ++count;
            }

        }

        /* after exiting inner for loop, if count is still 0, the card chosen from the deck isn't already in input_array. so it's added to input_array */
        if(count == 0){
            strcpy(input_array[i], deck[randInt]);
        }

    }
}
```

But once I run it over and over enough times, eventually I get weird/unexpected/random values (see images of output below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZmdB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNPGt.jpg

I've gone through every line of code and double checked everything. I have no idea what's going wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the source code, the images are unreadable.

Comment: Also, the loops seem to be wrong like a copy paste problem, are you sure both loop up to `i < 5` and `j < 5`? And your `main()` signature is wrong it's `int main()` which means that you are not using compiler warnings and hence some subtle mistakes might be hidden from you.

Comment: @iharob why are the loops wrong? the outer for loop runs 5 times, ensuring 5 cards are saved to input_array. and the inner for loop checks each element in the input_array to avoid duplicates

Comment: The biggest problem is that if the code detects a duplicate, it still advances to the next card (increments `i`). The value of `i` should only increment after a non-duplicate has been selected and the `strcpy` has been executed.

Comment: @0100100001101001 do not post links, post the output just copy it and paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code exhibits Undefined Behavior here:

```
if(strcmp(input_array[j], deck [randInt]) == 0){
```

Because `input_array` isn't initialized and contains "garbage" values.

To fix it, change

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
```

To

```
for(j = i-1; j >= 0; j--){
```

Also add append an `else` part:

```
if(count == 0){
         strcpy(input_array[i], deck [randInt]);
     }
else{
         input_array[i][0]='\0';
     }
```

`input_array[i][0]='\0';` is done to NUL-terminate `input_array[i]` so that it gets initialized and the `printf` in `main` does not print wierd things.